# Calculator WiFi usage on Marshmallow, Nexus 5? What?

Tags: wi-fi, security, nexus-5, data-monitoring, calculator

I have not used the calculator app.  I also don't know why it would be using the wifi or any kind of external data.  Yet behold, below:

[image: Calculator app using a lot of wifi data]

I flashed 6.0 recently and restored some apps from an old backup, but nothing that looked like calculator.  Should I be concerned, or is this a known thing?

Comment: For some reason, I believe it should be Chrome (or other browser that you mainly use), but I have no idea why Android refers to Calculator instead. Perhaps a mismatch in internal app ID (not based on package name) on Android system after restoring the old backup... I don't know...

Answer (score -2):

First off,
   They no longer uses Floating point arithmetic al which I read from a blog.
Second, 
    Marshmallow have introduced a lot of new features in its calculator which does uses internet for floating/decimal calculations for user-friendly UI and other touch gizmos. Currently its a kind of prototype, so it'll be downloading a bit for the updates but you can always disable the app from system settings.
You can see the new features from this site - http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/06/12/android-m-feature-spotlight-the-stock-calculator-app-has-been-overhauled-no-longer-uses-floating-point-arithmetic/

Comment: But OP never used Calculator app, and Calculator using 1.79GB is actually scary. Also, nowhere on the link that says Calculator needs internet for calculation (and I *really* doubt for simple calculation like this) .

Comment: Yeh but they said that they are trying to get the new features user friendly for people so they are making a lot of updates so obviously there are a lot of new updates and new downloads will be there, its just like google translator.

Comment: But the app doesn't need any permissions, and thus cannot use internet access...

Comment: David, 1.79GB of total updates for such a simple and small app is unrealistic. You're talking about small app updates, not System updates to Android, correct? If 1.79GB doesn't ring bells, expand it into MBs and that would be beyond 1700MBs. Are you saying those new flashy features consumed more than 1700MBs? Can you link cases similar to  the one OP has?  Without similar cases or a strong evidence which shows that Calculator app can consume such huge amount of data and on top of it, without being used by a user, your answer would be considered nothing beyond baseless opinion.